# Variances of the principal components in Ewin Tang's PCA algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, machine-learning

In [Quantum-inspired classical algorithms for principal component analysis and supervised clustering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00414), the PCA algorithm requires that the variances of the principal vectors differ by at least a constant fraction of the Frobenius norm squared ($\sigma_{i+1}^2 - \sigma_i^2 \ge \eta ||A||_{F}^2$) and that the variance is above a certain constant $\sigma^2$. Can the assumption that the principal vectors have different variances be dropped and the output changed to just the hypervolume created by all the (unordered) principal vectors with at least a certain variance, $\sigma^2$? And, if so, what is the modified algorithm's computational complexity? From the remark,

> As we assume our eigenvalues have an $\eta ||A||_F^2$
>   gap, the precise eigenvector $|v_j\rangle$ sampled can be identified
>   by the eigenvalue estimate. Then, by computing enough
>   samples, we can learn all of the eigenvalues of at least $\sigma^2$
>   and get the corresponding states

It seems like this should be fine, but later Tang adds,

> Note that we crucially use the assumptions in Problem 7
>   for our QML algorithm: without guarantee on the gap or
>   that $\sigma_i \ge \sigma$, finding the top k singular vectors would be
>   intractable, even with samples of $|v_i\rangle$’s.

leaves open the possibility it wouldn't work.